# Как подключить Bootstrap Notify

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

Хочу установить у себя сообщения от бутстрап.

подключил скрипт:

```
<script src="/../js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/../../bootstrap_notify/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
```

пути правильные, при вызове: `$.notify("Hello World");`

возникает ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function
```

Что я делаю нетак?

​

Answer (score 0):

Следующий код показывает правильный вызов Bootstrap Notify:

```js
$.notify("Hello World");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify/releases/download/3.1.3/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не работает все равно и вниз ставил и вверх ошибка все равно возникает. Может ли это быть потому, что я использую $.notify в своем скрипте? Подключаю его так:
$this->registerJsFile('/../../js/function_window.js');
он вставлен ниже всех остальных скриптов

Comment: Не может быть такого.